# i am getting this error, Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5002, throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, port, nodejs-server

I am getting this error whenever I try to run the code. I have tried Ctrl+C as well and tried different port too but its not working. I have also used command to kill all already running port.
This is the below Code. i have used this command taskkill /im node.exe. i hope there is no issue in code. its technical issue.

```
  const express= require('express') 
  const bodyParser=require('body-parser') 
  const mysql=require('mysql')

  const app= express()
   const port=process.env.PORT || 5002


  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

  app.use(bodyParser.json())

 //mysql
const pool=mysql.createPool({

connectionLimit:10,
host           :'localhost',
user           :'root',
password       :'',
database       :'nodejs_beers'

})

 //Get All beers
 app.get('',(req,res)=>{

    pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{

        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadID}`)

        connection.query('SELECT * from beers',(err,rows)=>{

            connection.release()

            if(!err){
                res.send(rows)
            }
            else{
                console.log(err)

            }
        })

    })


   })

   //delete A beer by id
   app.delete('/:id',(req,res)=>{

    pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{

        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadID}`)

        connection.query('DELETE from beers WHERE id = ?',[req.params.id],(err,rows)=>{

            connection.release()

            if(!err){
                res.send(`Beer with the id ${[req.params.id]} has been deleted`)
            }
            else{
                console.log(err)

            }
        })

     })


   })

  //Inser A beer 
  app.delete('',(req,res)=>{

    pool.getConnection((err,connection)=>{

        if(err) throw err
        console.log(`connected as id ${connection.threadID}`)
        const params=req.body

        connection.query('INSERT INTO beers SET = ?',params,[req.params.id],(err,rows)=>{

            connection.release()

            if(!err){
                res.send(`Beer with the id: ${params.id} has been added`)
            }
            else{
                console.log(err)

            }
        })

    })


   })



  //listen on environment port
  app.listen(port,()=>console.log('listen on port  $(port)'))
```

Answer (score 1):

this error tells that the port is already in use.

which means your server is not shutdown and you try to run another one in another terminal for exemple.
Or another program is really using the port.
you can try this to know which programm uses a port : https://veerasundar.com/blog/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port

if you cant find who is using the port, just change the port you are running on.